# Was I right to call off a <10BB stack in late position with 66?

Tags: texas-hold-em, tournament, live, hand

I was playing a free tournament live with approx. 30 players remaining from 50 entrants, blinds were 150/300 and I had 1k or 2k in my stack.

I had `66` in relatively late position and a player who had me covered on my right shoved. I called and Villain showed `KQo`.

Was this a good call? This was a coinflip and I was in push/fold mode because I had under 10BB.

I calculated the equity of `66` vs `KQo` - the `66` is a 53.48% favourite.

Comment: I think you have a 53% of winning so its a good call and being short on chips you had no choice really.

Comment: I get English may be a second language but your two questions are low quality.  1k-2k chips - be more exact.  "Is this a classic race?" is not the proper question here.

Answer (score 1):

Most (if not all) push fold charts would have a pair with 3-6 bb push.

You don't provide your position, exact stack size, and number of players.

An early push from the big stack represents a strong hand. A coin flip is about the best you can hope for.  But you also have better chance of heads up as it should fold out marginal hands.

If you are on the button 8 handed then you have 5 more hands to get a better hand before you are in the BB.  You might wake up with QQ, KK, AA, AK in early position where you actually want callers and will get them as they know you have to push with a wide range.

The question is how did you get to 3-6 bb in the first place.  If you are following a push fold chart then it is real rare to get there unless you lose an all in to a smaller stack.

Comment: Started with 5k stack lost some chips then I had AKs and lost 1.5k chips in one hand(raised 500 preflop) on the flop bet 1k (pot was 1.5k)

Comment: Really you bet 1k and left 1k - 2k behind?   That is bad play.

Comment: when I played with AKs there were blinds lower 50/100 or 100/200

Comment: If you bet 1k and left 1k - 2k behind that is bad play.

Comment: I don't wanted to play all in cause it was an early stage of tournament and folded a lot of hands I usually don't do this as much

Comment: @Grisza Sorry I tried to help.  I will be sure to not try in the future.

Comment: thx for feedback :)

Answer (score 0):

You had too short stack (~3-6 big blinds) so you had to push there. Having such a short stack you have to push every pair and Ax hand + all suited connectors

Answer (score 0):

Just because he was on your right doesn't mean he was in an early position. You need to exactly know which position you and the villain were sitting. Secondly, you said he was a big stack - but how big? Bigger than your 6BB doesn't mean he was a big stack. Was it at least 20-25BB? These factors are important and therefore you question can only be answered correctly if you ask it in a correct way. A good player with a big stack will never shove 66 in an early position.

In general, you call is compulsory under any circumstances. Even if raises 3BB, limps and another guy raises, etc., even there is a crazy action in front of you you have to shove KQo with <6BB. And also, in a free tournament you cannot expect good solid players - will be lots of shoves making tournament a bit of crap shoot.

Comment: Although the question is very poorly written, I think Hero had `66`, not the `KQo`. Doesn't really change your answer or the relevant advice though.